# Devise email custom 'from' parameter based on logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have an app in which companies can add customers. Each company has its own email.

Currently, when a new customer is created, they receive devise emails (confirmation, password reset etc.) through our domain email, but I want to the customers to see the email as being sent from the one specified by the company instead.

How can I intercept these emails and set the `from` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer) article. It describe how to create custom mailer for Devise.

Inside of your custom mailer you can assign appropriate values to `from` field.

Comment: But how do I pass arguments to the default devise emails?